# Could not find metadata {xxx} maven-metadata.xml in local

Tags: maven

Getting this error on this one dependency. It worked yesterday when I stopped for the day, and then did not work today when I started again. I didn't shutdown any apps, let alone the computer. Other dependencies are working fine, and I can see that the supposedly missing file is in the correct directory in the local repository.

**Here's a view of the file in the repository**

```
$ cd /c/users/thomsen.dean/.m2/repository/oes-common/oes-common/

thomsen.dean@US-PRECXIVJZ MINGW64 /c/users/thomsen.dean/.m2/repository/oes-common/oes-common
$ ls -l
total 9
-rw-r--r-- 1 thomsen.dean 1049089 304 Oct  8  2014 maven-metadata.xml
drwxr-xr-x 1 thomsen.dean 1049089   0 Sep  8 10:44 RELEASE/
-rw-r--r-- 1 thomsen.dean 1049089 555 Sep  8 10:44 resolver-status.properties
```

You can see that the mave-metadata.xml file is present, and here's the content of the file.

```
$ cat maven-metadata.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>oes-common</groupId>
  <artifactId>oes-common</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <release>RELEASE</release>
    <versions>
      <version>RELEASE</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20141008090909</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

**Here's the maven command and the error**

The error is: "Could not find metadata oes-common:oes-common/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\thomsen.dean.m2\repository)". But you can see from the above that the file exists and does not appear to be corrupted.

```
$ mvn clean install -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CCDRCDWeb 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.403 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-08T13:21:05-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project CCDRCDWeb: Could not resolve dependencies for project CCDRCDWeb:CCDRCDWeb:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at oes-common:oes-common:jar:RELEASE: Failed to read artifact descriptor for oes-common:oes-common:jar:RELEASE: Failed to resolve version for oes-common:oes-common:jar:RELEASE: Could not find metadata oes-common:oes-common/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\thomsen.dean\.m2\repository) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project CCDRCDWeb: Could not resolve dependencies for project CCDRCDWeb:CCDRCDWeb:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at oes-common:oes-common:jar:RELEASE
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:221)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:245)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:199)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project CCDRCDWeb:CCDRCDWeb:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at oes-common:oes-common:jar:RELEASE
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at oes-common:oes-common:jar:RELEASE
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for oes-common:oes-common:jar:RELEASE
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:245)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.VersionResolutionException: Failed to resolve version for oes-common:oes-common:jar:RELEASE: Could not find metadata oes-common:oes-common/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\thomsen.dean\.m2\repository)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.resolveVersion(DefaultVersionResolver.java:300)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:231)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataNotFoundException: Could not find metadata oes-common:oes-common/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\thomsen.dean\.m2\repository)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolve(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:247)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolveMetadata(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:205)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.resolveVersion(DefaultVersionResolver.java:237)
        ... 34 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

**Here a two dependencies from the pom.xml.** 

This one works

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>oes-dataobjects</groupId>
    <artifactId>oes-dataobjects</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This one does not work

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>oes-common</groupId>
    <artifactId>oes-common</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have tried to delete the directory in the local repository and recreate it.

I have edited the file to make sure it was accessible.

I can't figure out what maven is complaining about.

Hopefully someone out there has seen this before and can explain what is going wrong.